# How to change boxplots point color without overriding fill groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make boxplots that display three characteristic of the data (SiteID, Group, & TreatmentID). I am able to successfully represent two of the variables (SiteID and Group) as shown in the code below, but when I try to change the color of the points in the boxplot to represent my third characteristic (TreatmentID), it overrides the original grouping. Anybody have any idea how I could address this?

Here is my code:

```
myData <- structure(list(SiteID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Shale Hills", "Sleepers River"), class = "factor"),  TreatmentID = c("A", "R", "A", "R", "A", "R", "A", "R", "A", "R", "A", "R"), DOCmgkg = c(3.63, 6.43, 7.48, 10.04, 7.3, 8.2, 3.1, 8.1 ,6.36 , 1.8, 4.5, 5.4)), row.names = c("4", "8", "16", "20", "24", "28", "32", "36", "40", "44", "48", "52"), class = "data.frame")

# Bring in plot basics
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(myData, aes(x=SiteID, y=DOCmgkg, fill=Group)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(1))

# Successful attempt at displaying two characteritics
p + geom_point(position=position_dodge(1), pch=21)

# Unsuccessful attempt at displaying three characteritics
p + geom_point(position=position_dodge(1), pch=21, aes(fill=factor(TreatmentID)))
```

Best,
Thomas

Comment: Can you elaborate on your expected output? On your last line, I'm seeing A, R, Shale Hills, and Sleepers River all with different colors.

Comment: If you notice in the second plot, the points are shifted over and no longer fit within the boxplots they are associated with. What I am looking to accomplish is to color the points without having them move on the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, misread the original question. Answer is below, just adding the `group` parameter to `geom_point`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives your expected output with only a minor change, adding the `group` parameter to the `geom_point` aesthetics

```r
p + geom_point(position=position_dodge(1),
               pch=21,
               aes(fill=factor(TreatmentID), group=Group))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define a full `aes` for each plotting parameters (`geom_boxplot` and `geom_point`) and and remove `aes` from `ggplot()`.

Also, you can use `pch = 16` to get a full circle point filled with the same color than the border. Like that, you can replace `aes(fill...` by `aes(color...` avoiding you to pass twice `fill` in your plotting condition and you can use `scale_color_manual` to define colors only for points.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = myData) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(1), aes(x=SiteID, y=DOCmgkg, fill = Group)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(1), pch=16, aes(x = SiteID, y=DOCmgkg, group = Group, color =factor(TreatmentID)),size = 5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "darkorange"))
```

[image]

Is it what you were looking for ?

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you